# Consuming onedrive rest api in development environment using localhost

Tags: oauth, onedrive

Want to access list of files stored in one drive using jquery.  REST API provides a parameter to redirect to the application namely redirect_uri, can it be localhost or it should be public domain.

How developer have to test onedrive rest api.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map your `redirect_uri` to `localhost`of your web server. This can be done by adding it in `host` file found under `\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

After adding, it should look like

```
127.0.0.1    MyDomain.com
127.0.0.1    AnotherDomain.com
```

For more information on this, refer MSDN Dev Center - [Testing web apps locally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659751.aspx#Testing_web_apps_locally)