# OneDrive OAuth with Multiple Domains

Tags: onedrive

we are working on integrating OneDrive into our service. There is one issue we are facing with the OAuth redirects.
We have multiple deployment stages in our development process which include different base-urls. Starting with local development, multiple test deployments and one production. Is there any way to use different base urls for allowed redirect urls? Will this ever be supported? Why is it not? Dropbox and GDrive both support this.
My only idea would be to use different apps for the different stages which would introduce some complexity I would like to avoid.
What is the best process of handling different urls in development and production?

I found [Consuming onedrive rest api in development environment using localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762868/consuming-onedrive-rest-api-in-development-environment-using-localhost) which is not something I want to do since it will create confusion at some point if you forget to change your hosts file back.

Regards, 
arne

Comment: Added this request to make this available for dynamically created domains: http://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/7815039-add-support-multiple-domains-in-redirect-uri-witho If you are interested in this feature, please join my request.

Answer (score 0):

Daron from OneDrive here. Unfortunately that's not supported right now, so your best bet is to register different apps for your different stages. We've noted your feedback though.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Will try get it working with different apps.Is there any other way to provide feedback or look at open issues for OneDrive?